# How to find all strings that do not contain substring palindromes

Tags: string, algorithm, probability, combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

**Disclaimer**: This is a problem lifted from HackerRank, but their editorial answer wasn't sufficient so I hoped to get better answers. If it's against any policy, please let me know and I'll take this down.

**Problem**:
You are given two integers, N and M. Count the number of strings of length N under the alphabet set of size M that doesn't contain any palindromic string of the length greater than 1 as a consecutive substring.

N=2,M=2 -> 2 :: AA, **AB**, **BA**, BB

N=2,M=3 -> 6 :: AA, **AB**, **AC**, **BA**, BB, **BC**, **CA**, **CB**, CC

ABCDE counts as it does not contain any palindromic substrings.

ABCCC does not count as it does contain "CCC", a palindrome of length >1.

**Editorial**
Here is the provided answer which I think is wrong:

For N>=3, there are (M−2) ways to choose any next symbol (after the first two) - basically it should not coincide with the previous and pred-previous symbols, that aren't equal.

```
If N=1, return M

If N=2, return M * (M-1)

If N>=3, return M * (M-1) * (M-2)^(N-2)
```

counterexample: N=4, M=3, "ABCC"

**My Solution Try**
When I was working on this problem, I tried to find all the strings that contained palindromic substrings and subtracting that from the total, M^N. I ran into a lot of problems with over counting. For example, "ABABA" has "ABA","BAB","ABA" of n=3, and "ABABA" of n=5.

Thanks for any help in elucidating this problem. I really hope for a good answer to figure this out!

Comment: I don't see what your counterexample is supposed to show. It contains the palindrome `CC`, and it violates the stated constraint on palindrome-free strings, since it has a letter that is identical to the previous letter. Everything seems to be as the solution says it should be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose you build up palindrome-free strings one letter at a time. For the first letter, you have M choices, and for the second, you have M-1, since you can't use the first letter. This much is obvious.

For every letter after the first two, you can't use the previous letter, and you can't use the letter before that, so that's two choices eliminated. What about the other letters? Well, if using one of those creates a palindrome, it would have to be a palindrome of length at least 4 - but if adding a letter creates a palindrome of length K+2 for K>=2, the string must already have had a palindrome of length K for the new palindrome to build off of. (For K<2, this is okay.) Since the string didn't have any palindromes of length >=2, we can conclude that adding any letter other than the previous two letters is fine.

Thus, we have M choices for the first letter, M-1 choices for the second, and M-2 for every letter after that.